# Gitlab - routing LFS traffic through LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, cloudflare, gitlab

Gitlab (10.2.1) running on a local server (ubuntu 16.04). Goal is to grant remote contractors public access (`https://gitlab.example.com`) while those on premises route through lan for best performance (a huge repo with many large binaries)

We have a bit of a strange setup that mostly works: DNS and https are configured using Cloudflare signed cert to resolve public access to https and serve the gitlab web interface. Internally, git users point to the explicit LAN address `git@192.x.x.x:repo/name.git` via SSH. This works well for git traffic, but LFS traffic is still taking a round trip through the internet and cloudflare's routers, creating a significant slow down. I presume this is because gitlab does not support LFS over SSH?

I've tried a local override using hosts files to squash `gitlab.example.com` to `192.x.x.x`, but then we run into SSL errors because of server mismatch

I'm in over my head - is there a way to make this setup work? Or do I need to go back to drawing board? Do we need a custom DNS server? Do I need to set up multiple SSL certs? Any guidance in which direction to pursue would be appreciated.